# Character function in C

Tags: c, function, char

I want to make a function in C but clueless what to do
I know how to do it with integers but not with characters/strings

```
printf("\nEnter player %d name: ", i);

scanf ("%s", playername[i]);
```

This allows me to read name. %d is just a number above

I want to create a function where it generates a random number (I know how to do that) and then print out a greeting message

So something like this

```
int grmessage;
grmessage = rand () %4;



srand (time(NULL));

if (grmessage == 0)
printf("Welcome to the game, %s!\n" , playername[i]);
else if (grmessage == 1)
printf("Hello %s and welcome!\n" , playername[i]);
else if (grmessage == 2)
printf("%s has joined us! Say hello!\n" , playername[i]);
else if (grmessage == 3)
printf("Pleasure to have you in this game %s!\n" , playername[i]);
else if (grmessage == 4)
printf("Why hello there %s!\n" , playername[i]);
else 
printf("Say hello to %s who has entered the game.\n" , playername[i]);
```

Now can someone tell me how to put the above block of code in a function

So essentially

...

```
void texter (char a) { my code above }
```

and then when I call the function again to have it print out the text

```
printf("\nEnter player %d name: ", i);

scanf ("%s", playername[i]);

texter (playername[i]);
```

I know I already gave the code literally but just need to fix it and make it work as that's what I would do if it was an integer

Comment: I did not understand the requirement...can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Show your declaration for `playername`. Also consider using *line-oriented* functions to take user input (e.g. `fgets` or POSIX `getline`) rather than the `scanf` family. There are many hazards for new C programmers in `scanf`. It is fine to use if you fully-understand `man scanf`, otherwise, pay particular attention to what gets left in `stdin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a character array to store player's name (as you've already done). some thing like this:

```
char playername[no_of_players][100];

scanf ("%99s", playername[player_number]);  
//NOTE: %99s to avoid overwriting the terminating '\0' character
```

and **you can send a string as parameter to function by using `char*` datatype**

`texter()` function prototype:

```
void texter(char* name_sent) 
{
    //use name_sent to access the string sent into function 
}
```

function calling:

```
texter (playername[player_number]);
```

Additionally, just use `srand()` once at the beginning your `main()` function, don't use it in the `texter` function. see this: [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7343833/5281962)

Answer (score 0):

you should use srand() before using rand() in order to get more random-like results. And

```
playername[i]
```

is a string not a char. So your function declaration should be

```
void texter (char* a) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume `player name[i]` is a character, when using `scanf`, format specifier should be `%c`, not `%s`.

Assume `player name[i]` is a string (this may be what you intend to do), then when writing `void texter()` function, the parameter should be `char *playername` or `char player name[]` not `char`.